# Inconsistent data in Chrome Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

While debugging my Chrome extension I see the following multiple times:
[image]

On the one hand, the title of the object says `Array(2)`, but on the other hand, when expanding the object, it's evident that the array has only one element.

What's the source of this discrepancy? Is this a bug in the debugger or is there really an extra element in the array (maybe undefined?) that's for some reason is not visible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because an element was removed from the array after the console.log().

Then you have expanded the array.

Just try this on the chrome console:

```js
var myArray = ['value1', 'value2'];
console.log(myArray);
myArray.pop();
```

Then expand the log of `myArray`. You will see only one entry, but the already logged line still show 2 entries.

The content of the array is fetched when you expand, they are not duplicated for the log.